# Bertrand's ballot theorem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, probability-theory, number-theory, game-theory

I want to understand the dynamic programming equation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem theorem.
it is this

If i number of people voted for A and j number of people voted for B then dp[i][j] counts the number of ways voting can happen.

dp[ i ] [ j ] = dp[ i ] [ j - 1 ] + dp[ i - 1 ] [ j ] .

basically, I want to find the number of ways candidate A is in the winning position throughout. 
Can anyone explain the logic behind the dp equation ?
I think it works like this.
We have a sequence of A and B.In which A wins throughout. Now we add one more A to that sequence or add one more B to it.

Comment: Your question is missing something very basic: what does dp[i][j] count?

Comment: If i number of people voted for A and j number of people voted for B then dp[i][j] counts the number of ways voting can happen.

Comment: You should update your post with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N(p,q)$ be the number of sequences containing $p$ many A's and $q$ many B's, such that in every non-empty prefix, the number of A's strictly exceeds the number of B's. Clearly $N(p,q) = 0$ if $q \geq p$ and $q > 0$. When $p = q = 0$ there are no non-empty prefixes, and so $N(p,q) = 1$.

Suppose therefore that $p > q$, and consider any sequence satisfying the condition. If we remove the last element, we still get a sequence satisfying the condition. Conversely, whatever element we add, the resulting sequence will satisfy the condition, since $p > q$. We conclude that
$$
N(p,q) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } p=q=0, \\
0 & \text{ if } q \geq p \text{ and } q > 0, \\
N(p-1,q) + N(p,q-1) & \text{ if } p > q > 0, \\
N(p-1,q) & \text{ if } p > q = 0.
\end{cases}
$$